# OpenMP GCC GOMP wasteful barrier

Tags: gcc, openmp

I have the following program.
nv is around 100, dgemm is 20x100 or so, so there is plenty of work to go around:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1)
        for (int c = 0; c < int(nv); ++c) {
            omp::thread thread;                                               
            matrix &t3_c = vv_.at(omp::num_threads()+thread);
            if (terms.first) {
                blas::gemm(1, t2_, vvvo_, 1, t3_c);
                blas::gemm(1, vvvo_, t2_, 1, t3_c);
            }

            matrix &t3_b = vv_[thread];
            if (terms.second) {
                matrix &t2_ci = vo_[thread];
                blas::gemm(-1, t2_ci, Vjk_, 1, t3_c);
                blas::gemm(-1, t2_ci, Vkj_, 0, t3_b);
            }
        }
```

however with GCC 4.4, GOMP v1, the `gomp_barrier_wait_end` accounts for nearly 50% of runtime.  Changing `GOMP_SPINCOUNT` aleviates the overhead but then only 60% of cores are used.  Same for `OMP_WAIT_POLICY=passive`.  The system is Linux, 8 cores.

How can i get full utilization without spinning/waiting overhread

Comment: Just for fun, try changing the schedule to use "schedule(static)" and see what happens.

Comment: @ejd tried that too, same effect.

Comment: @Anycorn: did you solve the problem? I have the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

The barrier is a symptom, not the problem.   The reason that there's lots of waiting at the end of the loop is that some of the threads are done well before the others, and they all wait at the end of the for loop for quite a while until everyone's done.

This is a classic load imbalance problem, which is weird here, since it's just a bunch of matrix multiplies.   Are they of varying sizes?  How are they laid out in memory, in terms of NUMA stuff - are they all currently sitting in one core's cache, or are there other sharing issues?  Or, more simply -- are there only 9 matricies, so that the remaining 8 are doomed to be stuck waiting for whoever got the last one?

When this sort of thing happens in a larger parallel block of code, sometime it's ok to proceed to the next block of code while some of the loop iterations aren't done yet; there you can add the `nowait` directive to the for which will override the default behaviour and get rid of the implied barrier.  Here, though, since the parallel block is exactly the size of the for loop, that can't really help.

Comment: there are 100 matrices, load imbalance is highly unlikely.  false sharing is improbable too.  nowait makes things much much worse speed-wise.

Comment: Unlikely or not, if there weren't load imbalance issues, your tasks wouldn't all be waiting at the end of a omp for.   nowait should also make exactly zero difference here if the code is as quoted above; it should just shift the implied barrier from the end of the for to the end of the parallel block...

Comment: and as suggested by @ejd 's comment, I suspect the reason the schedule is currently (dynamic,1) is because things were worse with the default scheduling and even dynamic with larger chunksize, yes?  Again, that's a sign of a load imbalance problem.   One way to see what's going on if your profiling tools don't do it for you are to time each loop iteration and print out the time with the appropriate thread index and iteration number and see if you can figure out where the imbalance comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your BLAS implementation also calls OpenMP inside? Unless you only see one call to `gomp_barrier_wait_end`.

Comment: That's definitely an idea worth checking out.   Even if it's using pthreads, there may be some interaction there.

Comment: Anyway, you should not care about the barrier that much (unless your goal is to reduce barrier overhead), but for your wallclock time: what is the speedup you are getting?